# Error when using LIKE in report builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to use LIKE in report builder and I got this error:

> An error occurred while reading data from the query result set.
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 245)

this is my code:

```
select count(*) from projects where received LIKE '%'+@received+'%'
and institution# = @institution and program# = @program
```

how could i solve it?

Comment: You probably need to explicitly convert `@Received` to a varchar - `WHERE received LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @received) +'%'.

Comment: thank you , i use your solution and it is work.

Comment: CONVERT is SQL Server specific, CAST is ANSI.

Answer (score -1):

`@received` appears to be an integer. You will need to explicitly convert to `varchar()`:

```
select count(*) from projects 
where received LIKE '%' + cast(@received as varchar(20)) + '%'
...
```